# I'm trying to use the likebox plugin on my website with the "iframe" option and it's not working

Tags: facebook-like

I coped and pasted the code that is supplied, and the i frame is displaying with a "page cannot be found". Does anyone know if this is just a bug? Or if they're not maintaining the "iframe" option anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is still using the iframe option. Did you put in the link to your Facebook page? You might try using the tool again. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/